# scala overrides java class method with inner class and type parameters

Tags: java, scala, types, scala-java-interop

I'm working on a java library in scala. There's an abstract class in java:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<I, O> implements Serializable {
    public abstract class Context {
        public abstract void output(O output) 
    }
    public abstract class ProcessContext extends Context {
        public abstract I element()
    }

    // method to override
    public abstract void process(ProcessContext c) throws Exception
    ...
}
```

And I've tried to impl a sub-class in scala:

```
class SubClass extends SomeClass[String, String] {
    override def process(c: SubClass.this.type#ProcessContext) {
        val elem = c.element()

        // problem: elem is not recognized as a string
        if (elem.trim.isEmpty) {...}
        ...
    }
}
```

So the problem is that the type parameter is kind of 'lost' in the scala sub-class. The `elem` variable is not recognized as a string.

I've seen the blog by Jeff Hodges at http://www.somethingsimilar.com/2011/01/13/tricky-things-in-scala/ , and tried:

```
abstract class SSomeClass[I, O] extends DoFn[I, O] {
    type Context = DoFn[I, O]#Context
    type ProcessContext = DoFn[I, O]#ProcessContext
}
class SubClass extends SSomeClass[String, String] {
    ...
    // same problem as before
}
```

But same problem persists.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying `val elem = c.element()` in IDE, if so can you check the type of elem. Also, did you try `val elem: String` ??

Answer (score 1):

This says that the type of `element` is `String`. There are probably easier ways to demonstrate it. `(currentMirror reflect x).symbol` yields the ClassSymbol.

```
package interop

import reflect.runtime._, universe._

class Subber extends SomeClass[String, String] {
  override def process(c: SomeClass[String, String]#ProcessContext) = {
    val x = c.element
    debug(x)
  }
  def debug[A: TypeTag](a: A) = Console println implicitly[TypeTag[A]]
}
object Test extends App {
  val s = new Subber()
  val c = new s.ProcessContext { def element = "hi" ; def output(x: String) = () }
  s process c
}
```